# How can I group my values into columns by category in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

Maybe I didn't word it correctly because I'm not sure how to word it, but what I want to do is to go from Table A to table B:

Table A:

| Category | Code | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B1B | Green |
| A | A1A | Blue |
| B | C1C | Olive |
| B | B1B | Green |
| B | EF9 | Red |
| B | K32 | Purple |

Table B:

| Category | Code1 | Color1 | Code2 | Color2 | Code3 | Color3 | Code4 | Color4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | AIA | Green | B1B | Blue |  |  |  |  |
| B | C1C | Olive | B1B | Blue | EF9 | Red | K32 | Purple |

We have a lot of categories with colors for each one, for some tests they need each code and color to be in one row per category and we don't know how to do it, take into account that there are categories with 16 colors, some with 2 and such so no defined number of columns. Any tips? TIA

Comment: In accord with forum guidelines, please edit your question to include what you have tried and where that code has run into problems. Also, please explain the logic involved in creating Table B from Table A. There does not seem to be any logical match between Category, Code and Color in Table B, compared with Table A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your results in Table B don't seem to match up with the data in Table A, it's not clear exactly what you want.  In particular, I would expect that for Category A, the Code1 and Color1 entries would match the same line in Table A, but you show, in Table A, `B1B|Green` and in Table B, you show, for `Code1|Color1`  `A1A|Green`  And multiple other similar mismatches.

If those mismatches are just a sloppy way of expressing your desired results, and you actually want them to match, you can

- Group by Category
- For each sub group

  - Unpivot the Code and Color columns
  - Create unique names for each Color/Code attribute pair
  - Then Pivot on the Attribute column with no aggregation

`Home=>Transform Data=>Home=>Advanced Editor`
*Paste the code below into the window that opens, and it will create your data and what I think might be your desired outcome*

```
let

//Change next two lines to reflect your actual data source and typing
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUXIydAKS7kWpqXlKsToQMUdDsExOaSpYCKTA2dAZSPrnZJYhxNC1gniubpZAMig1BS7ibWwEJANKiwpygFpjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Category = _t, Code = _t, Color = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"Code", type text}, {"Color", type text}}),

//Group By Category
    #"Group Category" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type","Category", {
        {"Grouped", (t)=> let 
            #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(t, {"Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

        //create unique names for each code/color pair in the Attribute column => "Merged" column
            #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
            #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 2), Int64.Type),
            #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Integer-Division", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[Attribute], Text.From([#"Integer-Division"], "en-US")}, "."), type text),

        //Remove unneeded columns and then Pivot (with no aggregation) on the Merged column
            #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Attribute", "Index", "Integer-Division"}),
            Pivot = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", #"Removed Columns"[Merged],"Merged","Value")
        in 
            Pivot
            }
        }),

//Combine the resultant subtables
    #"Combine Tables" = Table.Combine(#"Group Category"[Grouped])
in
    #"Combine Tables"
```

***Source***
[image]   -

***Results***
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah I had a bad way of expressing it but your answer is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot. Also, it might be a lot but do you know how could I have worded what I wanted in the answer? English is not my first language so I couldn't put into words the desired outcome but I'm sure there are ways to make it concise.